# Преобразование из char в int

Tags: c, вывод, ввод, преобразование-типов

У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором записаны числовые данные. И после того как я пишу функцию fscanf(fp,"%d",&mas[0][0]). При выводе в printf я получаю вместо числового значения символа к примеру '1'(ведь в текстовом файле как я понимаю все хранится в виде символов) число 1. Каким образом это происходит?

Comment: Не ясно, что именно вы хотите вывести: число или символ? Если вы прочитали число 1, используя спецификатор формата %d, то и будет выведено это число.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `fscanf` - это функция форматированного ввода. Спецификатор формата `%d` в функции `fscanf` как раз и говорит ей: прочитай из файла все последовательные символы, пока они соответствуют формату целого числа

```
[пробельные символы][+/-](цифра)(цифра)...(цифра)
```

затем преобразуй их в соответствующее целочисленное значение типа `int` и запиши его в аргумент.

Comment: то есть указывая спецификатор формата %d, символы '+', '-', '1', '2' и т.д. будут расцениваться как числа 1,2 и т .д.?

Comment: @Yaroslav: Символы `1`, `2` и т.д. будут расцениваться как *цифры* строковой записи числа. Когда будет найдено, где заканчивается запись числа, она будет преобразована в целый тип.

Comment: все понял, спасибо.